# How to hide few fields from create.gsp form in grails view folder?

Tags: html, grails, gsp, grails-domain-class

I want to hide few fields in grails create.gsp file for a table. I cannot use `column display false` constraint because I want the field to be visible in index page table view.

By default the code for create.gsp contains the following:

```
            <g:form resource="${this.tablename}" method="POST">
                <fieldset class="form">
                    <f:all bean="tablename"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="buttons">
                    <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
                </fieldset>
            </g:form>
```

How do I skip some specific 2-3 fields in  `<f:all bean = "tablename"/>` part of code?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I skip some specific 2-3 fields in <f:all bean = "tablename"/>
> part of code?

You can exclude attributes using the `except` attribute of the tag which accepts a comma-separated list of properties that should be skipped.

See https://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/latest/ref/Tags/all.html for more info.

Comment: https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields/blob/5a80d3d51868a1606365d5208d4694e1e31d7ebc/src/test/groovy/grails/plugin/formfields/taglib/DisplayTagSpec.groovy#L50-L58 shows an example of using `except`.